# How to change order of JSON output

Tags: jquery, json, sorting

Part of an app I'm building fetches a JSON feed of a playlist, my jQuery `each` code is this:

```
$.each(data, function (i, data) {
                        var playlistTracks = '<li><span>' + data.TIT2 + '</span> &mdash; ' + data.TPE1 + '</li>';
                        $('section.player div.playlist-view ul.playlist').append(playlistTracks);
                    });
```

This outputs the feed items from oldest to newest songs top to bottom. What I'm wondering is how I can change the order of this output to display the newest song at the top, and going down to the oldest songs. Can anyone help me out with rearranging this?

On a side note I'd also like to remove the *last* item/song in this playlist, as it's data is dismayed in the music player as 'currently playing'. How can I remove this single item?

Thank you!

Comment: That is best handled by the server. It is always a better idea to reduce the processing at FE

Comment: @Sushanth-- The feed is being loaded in directly from the JSON URL using jQuery `ajax`, which I don't have control over. At this point I think I have to find a client side solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Spot the difference :)

```
$.each(data, function (i, data) {
                        var playlistTracks = '<li><span>' + data.TIT2 + '</span> &mdash; ' + data.TPE1 + '</li>';
                        $('section.player div.playlist-view ul.playlist').prepend(playlistTracks);
                    });
```

Answer: switch append for prepend

Comment: Damn, that was easy! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Should be able to do a reverse for loop:

```
for(var i = data.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    var playlistTracks = '<li><span>' + data[i].TIT2 + '</span> &mdash; ' + data[i].TPE1 + '</li>';
    $('section.player div.playlist-view ul.playlist').append(playlistTracks);
}
```

I'm not sure which end you want to remove the item from, but you can skip it by changing either

```
data.length-2
```

or

```
i >= 1
```

In your for loop.